# Backend Preview - get Image or IRRE data in Fluidtemplate

Tags: typo3, fluid

I use a Fluid Template for the backend: `mod.web_layout.tt_content.preview`

Is it possible to get images from FAL or data from an IRRE element in this template?

For the frontend there is the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor` for example. Could that also be used in backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a custom VH (IMO VHS also provides those) which gets you the data. It is not possible by default with the core.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up lately to use the hook `PageLayoutViewDrawItem` in `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\View\PageLayoutView` for doing that. That was the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

As Georg Ringer has already mentioned, you can render preview images in Fluid Preview Templates with the VHS ViewHelper `v:resource.record.fal`

https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Resource/Record/Fal.html

As record I must pass the argument `_all` because I have no other record available.

```html
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" 
      xmlns:v="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Vhs/ViewHelpers" 
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

<f:if condition="{assets}">

  <v:content.resources.fal field="assets" as="images" record="{_all}">
    <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
      <f:if condition="{image}">
        <f:image src="{image.id}" treatIdAsReference="1" width="100"/>
      </f:if>
    </f:for>
  </v:content.resources.fal>

</f:if>
</html>
```